# Why does gettimeofday return weird tv_sec?

Tags: c, gettimeofday

I have an application that calls `gettimeofday` to store the tv_sec in which that part of the code starts to run. This code is very simple:

```
struct timeval tvnow;
gettimeofday(&tvnow);
int initialTime = tvnow.tv_sec;
```

It normally works fine but sometimes I am getting unexpected results such as

```
tvnow = {tv_sec = 1024, tv_usec = 0}
initialTime = 1401591
```

Or

```
tvnow = {tv_sec = 1024, tv_usec = 0}
initialTime = 2439903
```

Why could this happen?

Regards

Comment: What happens if you change that `int initialTime` to `time_t initialTime`? My guess is you're on a 64 bit computer and it is overflowing the int.

Comment: Post how you determined `initialTime` has the value of `1401591`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `gettimeofday()` with the wrong number of arguments.  The resulting behavior is undefined.  If you don't want the timezone information, then pass `NULL` as the second argument:

```
struct timeval tvnow;
gettimeofday(&tvnow, NULL);
int initialTime = tvnow.tv_sec;
```

I'm going to suppose that somehow you're including a combination of headers that include a definition of `struct timeval` (or else you're providing your own definition), but not a prototype for `gettimeofday()`.  If there were a correct prototype visible at the point of the function call, then the code oughtn't to compile at all.  If your compiler doesn't issue a warning about the absence of a prototype then you ought to either figure out how to make it do so (and compile always that way), or get a better compiler.